# Displaying select dropdown as a menu with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to display a boostrap select dropdown as a menu like this picture.

Thanks in advance !

[See the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th9Vj.png)

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: What's a "boostrap select dropdown"? Is it a HTML select element, or a [Bootstrap dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#examples)?

Comment: I mean a bootstrap select. I've uploaded a picture for example

Comment: you need to show your work here @Kane

Comment: Ok i'll post my code

Answer (score 6):

Try the following snippet. I'm assuming you are using bootstrap 4 for your cause. You can refer their documentation for navbar and forms and combine the code.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#select-menu
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <select class="custom-select">
          <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: sorry ! it's not what i'm looking for. But anyway thank u for trying, i'll edit my post in order to explain it well.

Comment: That's better. If you can explain corectly what you needed.